# Is there a way to add a Crashplan friend without a friend code?

Tags: backup, crashplan

I've got a non-technical friend whose backup strategy is 'cross fingers and hope'. I've decided this is unacceptable (because I'll be the one called when hope stops working), so I installed Crashplan on her laptop. I want her to be able to back up to my machine, which is unfortunately two states away. I didn't copy my friend code before departing.

I have access to the Crashplan web interface. Is there a way to either discover my friend code from the web interface or add my computer as a backup destination without one?

Comment: You could easily "fix" this with the help of [Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/) or similar remote-control software once you get back. Teamviewer is very user-friendly and you could easily get your non-technical friend to start it up with you on the phone or even by email instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access into the remote machine, you can [configure using a headless client setup](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Configuring/Configuring_A_Headless_Client). Just forward the CrashPlan port by putting something like this into your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host remotebox
  HostName 193.12.32.12
  # Expose CrashPlan on local port 4200
  LocalForward 127.0.0.1:4200 127.0.0.1:4243
```

This will bring the [CrashPlan default port of 4243](http://support.code42.com/Administrator/3.6_And_4.0/Planning/TCP_And_UDP_Ports_Used_By_Code42_Products#CrashPlan_App_Ports) to your local port 4200, and you can then edit your `ui.properties` file to point to port 4200, and bam you're connected to CrashPlan daemon running on remotebox